# list.count() says 1 when there are no value in list

Tags: python, arrays, list, count

I am trying to count the frequency of all elements from 1 to N in a List A".
I have to do it within O(1) space that's why I'm appending the count value on the same list.
I am new to problem-solving in python.

```
def printfrequency(A,N):
#Your Code here
lis = []

for i in range(1,N+1):
    if i in A:
        A.append(A.count(i))
    else:
        A.append(0)       
for i in A[-N:]:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

this code is giving wrong value for input

N = 9

A = [9,2,5,7,9,2,2,1,4]

Output --> 1 3 1 1 1 0 1 0 2

Expected --> 1 3 0 1 1 0 1 0 2

This is working fine for some input like

N = 2

A = 2 3 2 3 5

Output --> 0 2 2 0 1

Expected --> 0 2 2 0 1

Comment: " I have to do it within O(1) space that's why I'm appending the count value on the same list." that doesnt really make it constant space.

Comment: why are you checking `if i in A:`?? You want to check if the element you are going to count is in `A`, not if the *index* is in `A`.

Comment: Once you append something to `A`, it's not the same list anymore, and the next counts will be wrong.

Comment: Doing this in constant space will always involve overwriting existing elements of the list with separate values, and most likely require you to make more passes over the input than if you could use O(n) space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you intend to do is adding 'N' elements to the end of the list which represent the counts of 1 to N. This means you are still allocating N spaces. So this is still O(N) space. Maybe you meant that the space you use has to be independent of the list length. In that case, yes you are right. It really depends on what question you are trying to answer.
2. Let's assume your current algorithm is right, you just haven't implemented it properly. Let's look at what your code does. Assume the list you get is `A = [1, 2, 1, 3]`. Then on the first run of the loop you count the number of 1's and it's 2. So you append that to the list.

   So we now have `A = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]`. On the second run of the loop, you ask it to count the 2's. And now there are two 2's, 1 from the original list and one from the appended part. `A.count` will count through the entire list. So what you want to do is count only the 2's from the original part. You can do this by

   i. Don't append the counts to A. Put them in a different list. For example, your `lis` variable. That way `A.count` will count things in the original list anyway.

   ii. Tell count to only use the list up till the original part:

```
length = len(A)

for i in range(1, N+1):
   if i in A[:length]:
       A.append(A[:length].count(i))
```

(i) is cleaner than (ii), so it should be preferred.

Comment: After this I am getting correct output. But I'm new to problem solving can you help me out to solve the TimeLimit. It is showing                                                                                       our program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit < 4.9sec

Answer (score 0):

To count the values in `A` you should not append any more value to `A`. Rather use the `lis` variable you created there. Fo example, like this

```py
def printfrequency(A,N):
    #Your Code here
    lis = []

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        if i in A:
            lis.append(A.count(i))
        else:
            lis.append(0)       
    for i in lis:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: The question is this .... in O(1) space     Given an array A[] of N positive integers which can contain integers from 1 to N where elements can be repeated or can be absent from the array. Your task is to count frequency of all elements from 1 to N.